# In Ubuntu, how do I remove all files by a certain user in the current directory

Tags: bash, ubuntu

How do I remove all files in the current directory by a certain user?

I have tried `find * -user userName` to find all files

Comment: This sort of question is generally more on topic over at [su]  ... http://superuser.com/search?q=delete+all+files+owned+by

Comment: Take a look at GNU finds' option `-delete`.

Comment: Thank you! @MichaelBerkowski Does find . -user userName -exec rm {}\; I just want to confirm that it only removes all files by a certain user in the current directory.

Comment: `-exec rm {} +` will be faster (but the results are the same)... You can use `-print` or even `-exec ls -l {} +` to verify the list before you remove them (highly recommended! UNIX is not always very forgiving).

Comment: @RNK Yes, assuming you are inside that directory, `find .` will only search (recursively) in the current directory.  I removed that comment though, because `-delete` is easier to remember than `-exec rm {} \;`

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: `rm` without options won't remove empty directories, `-delete` removes empty directories.

Comment: @Cyrus The question was about removing files, not directories :-) I would typically add a `-type f` to exclude any dirs, and then do a second one `find . -type d -exec rmdir`, as I don't like adding `-f` to `rm`.

Answer (score 1):

The `find` suggestions in the comments are all good, but take care not to recurse below the current directory if that's not what you want.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -user userName -exec rm -v {} \;
```

will remove only files owned by userName in the current directory.  It will also print out the name of each file it removes.

If you do want to recurse through subdirectories just remove the `maxdepth` argument:

```
find . -type f -user userName -exec rm -v {} \;
```